# How to sum a given number and it's reverse number in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, sum, reverse

```
const reversedNum = num => 
  parseFloat(num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) * Math.sign(num)

console.log(reversedNum(456))
```

Couldn't figure it out how to write code in order to sum `654 + 456`

Thank You very much!

Comment: Replace `Math.sign` with `num`

Answer (score 3):

```
const reversedNum = num => num + +num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return sum of num and reversedNum inside a function.

```
const sumOfNumAndReversedNum= num => {
  const reversedNum = parseFloat(num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) * Math.sign(num)
  return num + reversedNum
}

let userNumber = 456

console.log(sumOfNumAndReversedNum(userNumber))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a more performant way of reversing the number than turning it into a string, flipping it, and turning it back into an integer.

One option is to go through the number backwards by popping off the last integer (e.g., `123 % 10 === 3`) and adding it to your newly reversed number. You'll also need to multiply your reversed number by `10` in each iteration to move you to the next degree.

For example, given the number `123`:

```
123 % 10 = 3;
123 /= 10 = 12;
0 * 10 + 3 = 3;

1 % 10 = 2;
12 /= 10 = 1;
3 * 10 + 2 = 32

1 % 10 = 1;
1 /= 10 = 0;
32 * 10 + 1 = 321
```

This method will also automatically take care of negative numbers for you, leaving you something like:

```
function reverse(num) {
  let reversed = 0;
  
  while (num !== 0) {
    const popped = num % 10;
    num = parseInt(num / 10);
    if (reversed > Number.MAX_VALUE / 10 || (reversed === Number.MAX_VALUE / 10 && popped > 7)) return 0;
    if (reversed < Number.MIN_VALUE / 10 || (reversed === Number.MIN_VALUE / 10 && popped < -8)) return 0;

    reversed = reversed * 10 + popped;
  }
  
  return reversed;
}
```

Now you can simply call:

```
console.log(123 + reverse(123))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const reversedNum = num => 
  Number(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''))

console.log(reversedNum(456))
```

Do it!